# Why does the "Reset Pooled Connections" option not work for MySQL .NET Connector

Tags: mysql, connection-string

I'm using the latest version (6.2.3) of the net connector.  According to the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connector-net-connection-options.html) an option exists called "Reset Pooled Connections".  I have tried to disable this using the following connection string:

```
Data Source=DB;Database=DBName;UID=username;PWD=password;Max Pool Size=100;charset=utf8;Reset Pooled Connections=no;
```

I have tried values of both "no" and "false", and have tried all three options for the setting including "Reset Pooled Connections", "ResetPooledConnections", and "ResetConnections". However, all of these result in the same error:

```
Keyword not supported.
Parameter name: reset pooled connections
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like an error in the documentation, either it's just not implemented, or it has been implemented and since removed.(source code is [here](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~mysql-clr-team/connectornet/trunk/annotate/head:/MySql.Data/Provider/Source/MySqlConnectionStringBuilder.cs))

There's another option though,

> ```
>  Connection Reset
> ```
>
> When true, indicates the connection state is reset when removed
>   from the pool

edit, further investigation shows those 3 options were removed way,way back and replaced with the above "Connection Reset" parameter. Some info [here](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?38,142053))

Comment: I was looking at the source code as well.  And you are right, it seems the option was removed, and the Connection Reset is now being used. However, it defaults to false.  By watching the Network with Ethereal, it  seems that it is still sending out a ping, as well as another command to select the database. Is there any way to stop the connection from doing the ping, and the database selection?

Comment: No, atleast the ping is hardcoded at line 142 here: http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~mysql-clr-team/connectornet/6.2/annotate/head:/MySql.Data/Provider/Source/MySqlPool.cs